# In what way is JavaScript (ECMAScript) similar to Self and Scheme

Tags: javascript, scheme, ecmascript

When looking at the ECMAScript 4th Edition specification [here](http://www.ecmascript.org/es4/spec/overview.pdf) it mentions that

> ES3 is a simple, highly dynamic, object-based language that takes its major ideas from the languages Self and Scheme.

I'm not familiar with these two languages and cannot seem to find any mention of what exactly is similar to these languages in ECMAScript.

Would someone be able to explain to me the features that ECMAScript has taken from these languages?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Self myself, but I believe that JavaScript's extensive use of prototypes came from Self.

As for Scheme's influence, you need look no further than JS's first-class functions and lexical scoping (okay, so JS doesn't implement full lexical scoping in the way Scheme does, it implements function-level scoping, but still, it's close).

Comment: So am I correct in saying that JavaScript inherited the ideas of these languages rather than any specific functionality?

Comment: Sure, that sounds right to me.